# Using access token generated from googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token, returns UNAUTHENTICATED

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, postman, google-oauth, google-photos-api

I am trying to fetch my google photos albums in my website. Now to do that I am using the Google Photos API.

The problem is, I can successfully fetch an access token, but using the access token to call the google API fails with an UNAUTHENTICATED error.

Now, this is where it gets weirder...
When I run the same steps in postman, with fetching the access token and using that access token to call the google photos API, it works properly.
Also, if I use the access token generated by postman in my code, it works, but using the access token from my program in postman, and postman fails.

So I am not sure what went wrong where. I would appreciate any help here. Please someone help.

The following is my code

I use `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` to create an access token

```
fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "text/plain",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      grant_type: "refresh_token",
      client_id: "<client_id>",
      client_secret: "<client_secret>",
      refresh_token: "<refresh_token>",
    }),
  })
```

Now of course to get the client id and secret, we create a google dev account, create an app, and create oauth2 credentials in there and then i got it.
Also in the App, you search for the required APIs that you want to use and you allow it. In my case I allowed, photos and drive API
To get the refresh token, I went to the oauth playground and generated it from there. Now oauth playground has covered the user consent part of it. In the oauth playground also, i selected the correct scopes for drive and photos API

Now I know all my steps are correct until here, because, the response i get has the correct schema, with the access_token, the expiry and the correct scopes I mentioned above.

The problem is the part after here. When I try to use this token as below

```
const Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
const res = await fetch("https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/albums", {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization,
  },
});
```

It returns an error

```
{
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
}
```

Comment: I think that when the access token of `token` is a valid access token, your bottom script in your question works. Actually, when I use your script with a valid access token, no error occurs and the response values are returned. So, I'm worried that your access token might be an invalid access token. How about confirming this again?

Comment: Thanks for replying @Tanaike. I have a similar worry that the access token, generated might be invalid, but what's causing it to be invalid is a bigger concern, because I do not see another way to generate an access token other than the top script, which returns a response which is exactly similar to what I get in postman. So what am I exactly missing here and who or what should I refer to get the right answer?